# Prove that Bezout's coefficients given by the extended Euclidean algorithm are minimal in absolute value

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Bezout's lemma states that if a and b are integers, and at least one of them is non-zero, then there exist integers $x, y$ such that $$ax + by = gcd(a, b)$$
One way of finding such a pair $(x, y)$ is the extended Euclidean algorithm where in each step we express the remainder (until it becomes zero) as an integral linear combination of $a, b$. There exist many such pairs $x, y$ which satisfy Bezout's lemma for $a, b$ but the one given by the extended Euclidean algorithm are minimal in absolute value. How do I prove this?

Comment: Yes, there exist many pairs $x$, $y$, but do you understand the formula that gives all of them in terms of any one of them? From that, can you see which solution minimizes absolute value? and why the extended Euclidean algorithm gives you that solution?

Comment: You can observe that the Euclidean algorithm is equivalent to the continued fraction algorithm, hence $\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert}$ is the penultimate convergent of $\frac{b}{a}$, and that is the first neighbour of $\frac{b}{a}$ in any Farey sequence.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I know that if I've found a solution (x, y) and d = gcd(a, b) then all other solutions are given by (x - kb/d, y + ka/d) where k is an integer other than 0 but I don't know how to relate it to the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Well, one thing at a time. Knowing the general form of the solution, which solution is going to minimize the absolute value?

Comment: @Daniel, maybe something needs to be said about the case in which the gcd is not 1.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Assuming a, b are both greater than zero, then x, y must have opposite signs. If x < 0 then min |k| with + sign else min |k| with - sign will give the solution with minimal absolute values.

Comment: In the relatively prime case, it follows that there are only two solutions with $|x|\lt b$ and $|y|\lt a$ (and you can work out the analogous result for the not relatively prime case). Now can you see that the extended Euclidean algorithm always gets you to one of those two solutions?